# Component error in a custom sorting function in LWC

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to write a custom sorting function for a data table (LWC). I have done so far below (sample)

## sampledata.html

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table_fixed-layout >
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th onclick={sortTable}>NAME</th>
         <th onclick={sortTable}> PRICE</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <!-- Oppdata is from a simple query on Opportunity records -->
      <template for:each={oppdata} for:item='ct'>
          <tr key={ct.opp.Id} >
              <td> {ct.opp.Name}</td>
              <td> {ct.opp.Price}</td>
          </tr>
      </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## sampledata.js

```
 import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';

 export default class UsermanageOpportunity extends LightningElement {

  sortTable(){
    let data = this.oppdata;
    let x, switching, shouldSwitch;
    switching = true;

   while (switching) {
            switching = false;

            for ( x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
              nextvalue = data[x+1].opp.Name.toLowerCase();
              currvalue = data[x].opp.Name.toLowerCase(); 

                if(currvalue > nextvalue){
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (shouldSwitch) {
                /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                let temp = [];
                temp = data[x];
                data[x] = data[x+1];
                data[x+1] = temp;
                switching = true;
            }
   }

 }
 this.oppdata = data;
}
```

However I am getting an error during the switch statement as shown below. No idea 
 why the read only value of the object                          ..[image: Sorting error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a local variable to do that. sorting the same reference (which is read only) is being used hence you can not write that. You need to clone that record set. More details is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_private)

```
@track localOppData;

sortMethod() {
    localOppData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.oppdata));
    localOppData.sort(function (a, b) {
            var first = a.Name.toUpperCase();
            var second = b.Name.toUpperCase();
            if (first < second)
                return -1;
            if (first > second)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }); 
 }
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by sorting the same reference. I am assigning oppdata to data variable and doing the sorting.              
 'let data = this.oppdata'

Comment: By the term same reference, I want to convey that the variable did not get a new memory location. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.oppdata)); create a new memory allocation which is writeable.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks